# Get the Account Name of the List Item Author

Tags: spservices

Using the below SPServices call, I can get the display name of the author of a list item:

```
$().SPServices({
                operation: "GetListItems",
                async: false,
                listName: "MyList",
                CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields Properties='True' />",
                CAMLQuery: "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ID' /><Value Type='Integer'>" + id + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query>", 
                completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
                    $(xData.responseXML).find("[nodeName='z:row']").each(function() {
                        author = $(this).attr("ows_Author");
                    });
                }
            });
```

This gets me a name like "43#;John Doe". How can I get the account name instead? Like "john.doe". So I can use it to get the user's manager's account name.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the Users and Groups web service.  If you call the `GetUserCollectionFromWeb()` method, it will return an XML node containing all the users on the site.  You can then look up your specific user using the ID returned in your User node - in the case of the example - 43.

The web service will return a collection of User nodes which have an ID attribute one of which will match your ID, and a LoginName attribute which will be the information you are after.

The SPService reference to the service is [here](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Users%20and%20Groups&referringTitle=%24%28%29.SPServices)

The MSDN reference to the service is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms774345.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I've read that if you include:

```
<QueryOptions><ExpandUserField>TRUE</ExpandUserField></QueryOptions>
```

in your CAMLQuery, it will bring back the account name in addition to the display name.

However, it is not working in WSS for me, and I vaguely recall it might only work in MOSS.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this same thing in C#, using the format style of the username you provided, and used the class `SPFieldUserValue` to get the actual user object, seen below:

```
string user = new SPFieldUserValue(web, "43#;John Doe").User.Name;
```

I'm not familiar enough with the client object model to provide an example for you, but take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380878/how-to-get-sharepoint-user-object-from-the-assignedto-field-using-client-side-o). See if either of the two solutions provided help you. They are using the `FieldUserValue` class, the client object model implementation of the `SPFieldUserClass`.

Answer (score 0):

Just modify it. If you can get: `43#;John Doe`, then just do:

```
function getUserName(author) {
    var authorName = author.split(';')[1]; // 0 is "43#", while 1 is everything after the ";"
    var authorParts = authorName.split[' ']; // break it into an array based on spaces

    var authorUserName = "";

    // Now reconstruct it with dots
    for (var i=0; i<authorParts.length; i++) {
        authorUserName += authorParts[i] + ".";
    }
    authorUserName = authorUserName.trimEnd('.');
    return authorUserName;
}
```

And call it:

```
author = getUserName(author);
```